# Have any of you seen anything like this before? Where should someone go to publish a "new" function?

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-writing, publishing

I'm just some random bum calculus II student who was tinkering around with calculus and I think I came up with some new function on my own.
so the tl;dr of my function is that you take some function and project that function onto another one. The function is called $b(f(x),g(x))$ where $f(x)$ is the function, and $g(x)$ will be treated as the axis. Here are some picture examples.

$b(sin(.5x),5sin(.1x))$
[image: Heres one]

$b(sin(x),.01x^2)$
[image]

If it turns out that this is something new, where should I send it to to spread the word? Thank you!

Comment: Yeah... this isn't new at all.

Comment: Thats unfortunate, what is it called?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't, I was just kinda proud of myself for potentially coming up with something myself, and wanted to see how far I could go. Obviously I'm new to this sort of thing and I was just looking for advice :(

Comment: @wjmccann Don't be discouraged. Math.StackExchange isn't always very nice to newcomers, sorry. Can anyone provide a reference for where wjmccann can read more about what others have already done related to this?

Comment: You maybe interested in the related idea of parallel curves: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve

Comment: @JustinBenfield, I feel like that is outside the scope of my mathematical knowledge, but thank you I'll try to understand!

Comment: Also, regardless of if it is new, you should ask "is it interesting?" Newness is half the battle. If what you create doesn't simplify something difficult, or connect topics in a way that is meaningful, then chances are it won't get published just for being new.

Comment: Keep experimenting! The intuition and experience you’ll gain about the relationship between functions and their graphs by playing around like this is valuable, not to mention satisfying and fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this in the future, this is called a *non-linear change of coordinates*, and is apparently used frequently in special relativity

Answer (score 0):

Expounding on my comment, it's not actually too hard to give a fairly explicit set of (messy) expressions for the curve you are describing. To see how this can be done, consider the notion of parallel curves described in at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve. Here, what you basically do is move a fixed distance $d$ along the normal line at each point of the initial curve (your $g(x)$) to obtain the corresponding point on the parallel curve. This can be calculated based on the derivative of $g$, as the slope of the normal line is related to that of the tangent line (they differ by 90 degrees, or $\pi / 2$ radians). What you have done is to replace the constant $d$ with a function $f$ of the same $x$ as used in in $g$, hence the distance is now also a function of where you are on the $g$ function (so now, $d=f(x)$). It would not be too hard to give (messy) parametric equations for your $b$ function, which btw is generally actually a pair of functions, $b_x(x,f,g)$ (this returns the $x$-coordinates for points on the $b$ curve parametrically in terms of original $x$ values used in the $g$ function) and $b_y(x,f,g)$ (likewise for the $y$-coordinates, based on and same $x$), of one variable and 2 functions (of that same single variable).

Comment: Oh, well I have already came up with the equations. While not too pleasant I don't think they were super bad. For those equations, do you think it would be worthwhile to send the theorem/proof to some place? I'm not planning on going into pure mathematics, so I thought it would just be a little fun experience and a conversation starter.